# How to return multiple values from JQuery AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax, string

I'm making an AJAX call to a page that returns XML.  It turns out that I need to also return another standalone value, along with the XML.

Here is the JQuery AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "filesearch.asp",
        data: "action=getresponse,
        dataType: "text",
        cache: false, 
        success: function(data){

        var parsed   = data.split('DELIMITER');
        var xml      = data[0];
        var myvalue  = data[1];
}
```

The page that sends the response sends the XML and my value separated by the **DELIMITER** string. Also, I set the dataType so that it treats the full response as a text, and I'm assuming I should be able to simply split the string at the delimiter and access both values in my success function.  Firebug shows I get the full response correctly, but when I log **xml** and **myvalue** to the console, I get:

```
xml = < 
myvalue = ?
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already noticed: you have to use `parsed` instead of `data`...

But: Do not use plain-'text' but 'json' as your data type  and change your asp script to output valid JSON.
Then `data` is a JavaScript object so you don't have to mess around with splitting strings etc.

Comment: @ Thief - Good idea.  I actually turn the XML to JSON in my callback, but if I can send it in that format to begin with that would be great.  Any pointers on the best way to accomplish this in ASP?

Answer (score 1):

Wow.  Should've been:

```
var **parsed**   = data.split('DELIMITER');
var xml      = **parsed**[0];
var myvalue  = **parsed**[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to your answer.

the reason you are seeing `<` and `?` is because data is text which is an array of characters and as the xml starts as `<?xml` the first and second (0th and 1st) values are `<` and `?`